# More SQL headaches

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'd just like some general advice. My tables are structured like so (or rather, the tables I've been given to work with):

```
> Deliveries 
 ID (Primary Key) 
 customer
...(irrelevant fields)...


> DeliveryItems
ID (primary key)
deliveryid (links to ID of deliveries)
delivered (integer - 2 means delivered, 1 not delivered yet)
...(irrelevant fields)...
```

Anyway, in an SQL query I am creating, I need to do the following:

A user visits the page, which is the 'customer parameter for the deliveries - so it displays all deliveries linked to that customer. Then, I'll need a dynamically generated a column to display whether all my items have been delivered or not - so basically, if the count of items for that consignment is equal to the count of items for that consignment that have the status '2' are equal, all items for that delivery have been delivered. Any ideas? I've toyed around with joins but I'm confused :(

Thanks

Comment: Here, let me help. Just click on the checkbox next to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select d.*,
    case when di.TotalCount = DeliveredCount then 1 else 0 end as DeliveryComplete
from Deliveries d
inner join (
    select deliveryID, 
        count(*) TotalCount, 
        count(case when delivered = 2 then 1 end) as DeliveredCount
    from DeliveryItems 
    group by deliveryID
) di on d.ID = di.deliveryID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by with a little help from `case / when / then`:

```
select d.*, 
case 
   when exists (select * from DeliveryItems di 
                where di.deliveryid = d.id 
                and di.delivered <> 2)
   then 0
   else 1 
end as DeliveryComplete
from Deliveries d
where d.customer = @customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Case statement:

```
SELECT 
    DeliveryId, 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(Delivered) = 2 * COUNT(Id) THEN 'All items delivered'
        ELSE 'Not Delivered'
    END AS [Status]
FROM 
    DeliveryItems
GROUP BY 
    DeliveryId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one.

```
SELECT b.*
    , CASE WHEN a.min_delivered = 1 THEN 'Get back to work'
           ELSE 'All done!'
           END AS [Are they all done]
FROM
(
    SELECT customer
        , MIN(delivered) AS min_delivered
    FROM Deliveries a
    JOIN DeliveryItems b
        ON a.id = b.deliveryid
    WHERE a.customer = @customer
    GROUP BY customer
) a
JOIN Deliveries b
    ON a.customer = b.customer
```